# How to make app global in Express using coffeescript

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, express

I am trying to build an Express project in CoffeeScript. I am trying to make the `app` variable global so that I can use to anywhere - read configuration settings from it.

So far, I have tried this -

In my `app.coffee` file -

```
app = express()
app.configure ->
    app.set 'host', 'localhost'
http.createServer(app).listen 8888, ->
    console.log 'Server started'
exports.app = app
```

I want to access the `host` variable set above in one of my routes file. So, I tried in my route handler,

```
exports.app.get('host') # I get this undefined
```

How to accomplish this? Do I have to `require(app)` in my route file. `app.coffee` is requiring the module in which the route is present, obviously for routing, that is,

```
app.get '/', 'route_handler'
```

Comment: You want to reach `app` instance from your route handlers which are different files from the `app.js`, am i right?

Comment: Yes @TolgaAkyüz that is correct. I want to use `app` instance in my route handlers which is in a different file than `app.js`.

Comment: I solved it by requiring app in the route handler file and `exports.app = app` in the `app.js` file.

Comment: Can somebody explain me why the downvotes on the question? Is the question wrong in any way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your route handler will receive a request and response objects. Both of them have a reference to the global app variable. From there you can pick up the value that you set via app.set 'host' through req.app.settings.host

```
app.get '/', (req, res) -> 
    console.log req.app.settings.host
    # your code goes here
```